# jquery append innerHTML by id in new window after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, impersonation, window.open

I'm trying to use jquery to :

1. open a new window/tab (same domain, different page)
2. then add text to a text box (`id = "BUpdates_SQL_Statement"`)
3. then click this button: `<input type="submit" value="Apply Changes" name="BUpdates_Submit" id="BUpdates_Submit">`
4. then close the window

here's the onclick element in the starting page (we'll call it www.mydomain.com/firstpage):

`<li id="MainNav_Update"><span class="MainMenuText" onclick="runUpdateWindow();">Update</span></li>`

and here's the area I want to edit in the new window (we'll call it www.mydomain.com/secondpage)

```
<textarea id="BUpdates_SQL_Statement"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Apply Changes" id="BUpdates_Submit">
<a onclick="v$('BUpdates_Submit').click();return false;" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Apply Changes</span></a>
```

side note: `v$('BUpdates_Submit').click();return false;"` is for another external js file that has nothing to do with what I'm trying to do here.
and here's my jquery:

```
   function runUpdateWindow() {
        var updateWindow = window.open("www.mydomain.com/secondpage", "blank");
    }
        var updateSQL = 'UPDATE TABLE ...';

        $(updateWindow).on("load", function (){
        $("BUpdates_SQL_Statement", updateWindow.document).append(updateSQL);

$('BUpdates_Submit').trigger('click');
        });

        updateWindow.close();
```

The `www.mydomain.com/secondpage` is opening in a new tab, but the `BUpdates_SQL_Statement` should be:

```
<textarea id="BUpdates_SQL_Statement">
UPDATE TABLE...
</textarea>
```

but it's still blank.

I would sincerely appreciate any input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167965/how-do-you-communicate-between-2-browser-tabs-windows  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735706/is-it-possible-to-have-event-based-communication-between-browser-windows

Comment: @icktoofay The code I included pushes the boundaries of my abilities, as I am a complete noob. Forgive the proverbial "stupid question" but, how exactly would I use AJAX?

Comment: @KateTheGreat: I've added an answer that should outline how you'd use it, supposing the form you're trying to submit isn't very complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with doing an iframe rather than a new window:

```
function runUpdateWindow() {
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');

      frame.src = "www.mydomain.com/secondpage";

    document.body.appendChild(frame);

    var frameWindow = frame.contentWindow

    var updateSQL = 'UPDATE TABLE...';

    frameWindow.onload = function (){
        var textarea = frameWindow.document.getElementById("BUpdates_SQL_Statement");
        var button = frameWindow.document.getElementById("BUpdates_Submit");

        textarea.value = updateSQL;

frameWindow.v$('BUpdates_Submit').click();
    };

}
```

a huge thank you to  [Dagg Nabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886931/dagg-nabbit)  for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, what you're trying to do is automate filling out and submitting a form, and have selected a *seemingly* rather straightforward way of doing that. Whether or not that works, though, there's probably a simpler way.

Think about what happens when *you* open that other page, fill out the form, and press submit. If it's a normal HTML form with no JavaScript interfering with it, you'll probably just get a `POST` request. If I had this form, say:

```
<form action="run-sql" method="post">
    <textarea name="sql"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Run query">
</form>
```

When I submitted it with some SQL, the browser would send a `POST` request to `run-sql` with one parameter, `sql`. Firing off a `POST` request is relatively simple to do from JavaScript, at least in comparison to automating another web page. Firing off an HTTP request from JavaScript is typically called AJAX, and fortunately, jQuery makes it easy with [its `$.post` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

So how would one use it? In that specific example, it would be as simple as this:

```
var mySQL = "select * from employees";  // e.g.
jQuery.post("run-sql", {sql: mySQL}, function() {
    alert("Success!");
});
```

Now, some forms are not so simple as this, but it's worth a shot to see if your form is.